# cloudml extremely slow in R with small data set

Tags: r, keras, google-cloud-ml

I just started to use the cloudml package in R (rstudio). I'm using Keras to train a neural network using cloudml to get access to GPU.
This is a code from the book Deep learning with R that I'm runnig:

```R
library(tidyverse)
data_dir <- "jena_climate"
fname <- file.path(data_dir, "jena_climate_2009_2016.csv")
data <- read_csv(fname)

data <- data.matrix(data[,-1])

train_data <- data[1:200000,]
mean <- apply(train_data, 2, mean)
std <- apply(train_data, 2, sd)
data <- scale(data[,], center = mean, scale = std)


generator <- function(data, lookback, delay, min_index, max_index,
                  shuffle = FALSE, batch_size = 128, step = 6) {
if(is.null(max_index)) max_index <- nrow(data) - delay - 1
i <- min_index + lookback
function() {
    if (shuffle) {
        rows <- sample(c((min_index+lookback):max_index), size = batch_size)
    } else {
        if (i + batch_size >= max_index)
            i <<- min_index + lookback
        rows <- c(i:min(i+batch_size, max_index))
        i <<- i + length(rows)
    }

    samples <- array(0, dim = c(length(rows),
                                lookback/step,
                                dim(data)[[-1]]))
    targets <- array(0, dim = c(length(rows)))

    for (j in 1:length(rows)) {
        indices <- seq(rows[[j]] - lookback, rows[[j]],
                       length.out = dim(samples)[[2]])
        samples[j,,] <- data[indices,]
        targets[[j]] <- data[rows[[j]] + delay, 2]
    }

    list(samples, targets)
}
}


library(keras)

lookback <- 1440
step <- 6
delay <- 144
batch_size <- 128

train_gen <- generator(
data,
lookback = lookback,
delay = delay,
min_index = 1,
max_index = 200000,
shuffle = TRUE,
step = step,
batch_size = batch_size
)

val_gen <- generator(
data,
lookback = lookback,
delay = delay,
min_index = 200001,
max_index = 300000,
step = step,
batch_size = batch_size
)

test_gen <- generator(
data,
lookback = lookback,
delay = delay,
min_index = 300001,
max_index = NULL,
step = step,
batch_size = batch_size
)

val_steps <- (300000 - 200001 - lookback)/batch_size

test_steps <- (nrow(data) - 300001 - lookback)/batch_size



model <- keras_model_sequential() %>% 
layer_gru(units = 32, input_shape = list(NULL, dim(data)[[-1]])) %>% 
layer_dense(units = 1)

model %>% compile(
optimizer = optimizer_rmsprop(),
loss = "mae"
)

history <- model %>% fit_generator(
generator = train_gen,
steps_per_epoch = 500,
epochs = 20,
validation_data = val_gen,
validation_steps = val_steps
)
```

On my 2011 macbook air one epoch took 200-220s. Calling this function:

```R
cloudml_train("temperature.R", master_type = "standard_gpu")
```

where "standard_gpu" is supposed to be single NVIDIA Tesla K80 GPU, one epoch took around 240s and I got this message:

> ==> NOTE: You are uploading one or more large file(s), which would run significantly faster if you enable parallel composite uploads. This feature can be enabled by editing the "parallel_composite_upload_threshold" value in your .boto configuration file. However, note that if you do this large files will be uploaded as 'composite objects https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/composite-objects'_, which means that any user who downloads such objects will need to have a compiled crcmod installed (see "gsutil help crcmod"). This is because without a compiled crcmod, computing checksums on composite objects is so slow that gsutil disables downloads of composite objects.

I find this message strange since my data set is only ~40MB and I find it strange that my 2011 Macbook air is as fast (or even faster) as NVIDIA Tesla K80 GPU.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: It's possible that your model is not complex enough to fully utilize the GPU and thus moving to a faster GPU will not necessarily be helpful. Can you confirm that later epochs are roughly the same speed? Another thing you can do, more as a sanity check than anything, is to try a very large batch size (like 10x) and see if it makes a difference -- of course, that'll affect convergence, but you're more likely to see a difference in computation. Finally, you could also try adding more layers, bigger layers, etc.

Comment: I'm actually moving from CPU, I'm using macbook air (processor: 1,3 GHz i5, memory: 4 GB 1600 MHz DDR3). I can confirm that later epochs are roughly the same speed. In addition, the logs from Google Cloud Platform shows that the time between when I first saw the above mentioned message and the first epoch was around 40 minutes. I'm not sure what's happening during those 40 minutes BEFORE actual training starts.

Comment: So there are two problems: (1) the 40 minute delay which I think is related to the large file warning and (2) the throughput of training. I suspect #1 might be specific to the R package's handling of data and I don't have much info about that. My hypothesis on #2 is that the model itself is not complex enough to benefit from GPUs and/or is not optimally structured for GPUs (sometimes the input pipeline is the bottleneck, or copies from main memory, or preprocessing that should be done on CPU is done on GPU, etc.)

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I'll try making the model more complex and see if it make a difference.